# Differentiate A = $\frac{\sqrt{(π^2r^6 + 9V^2)}}{r}$ with respect to r.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

Differentiate **A = $\frac{\sqrt{(π^2r^6 + 9V^2)}}{r}$** with respect to r.

This function to the best of my knowledge is a multivariable function that can be differentiated partially, so I differentiated partially with respect to r and got $\frac{∂A}{∂r}$ =       $\frac{6π^2r^5}{2r\sqrt{(π^2r^6 + 9V^2)}} - \frac{\sqrt{(π^2r^6 + 9V^2)}}{r^2}$

The original function can also be expressed as $(AR)^2 = π^2r^6 + 9V^2$ which is an implicit function and when differentiated with respect to r, I got   $\frac{dA}{dr}$   =  $\frac{(6π^2r^5) + (18V\frac{dv}{dr}) - (2A^2r)}{2r^2A}$

My question is, are these two derivatives the same? since the function was just expressed in another form.

Comment: The full derivative $\frac{dA}{dr} = \frac{\partial A}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial A}{\partial V}\frac{dV}{dr}$.

Comment: Try separating the fraction, then substituting the expression for $A$ back into what you got for $dA/dr$. Do you notice any similarities to $\partial A/\partial r$?

Answer (score 1):

Your partial differentiation of $$ A \ \ =  \ \ \frac{\sqrt{ \ \pi^2r^6 \ + \ 9V^2 }}{r} \ \ $$
is a little troubling, in that the problem statement doesn't indicate whether $ \ V \ $ is a function of $ \ r \ $ as well.  Given that you want to compare your approaches, we should treat the derivative of $ \ V \ $ for both.

So if the area function is written as $ \ r^{-1}· ( \pi^2·r^6 \ + \ 9V^2 )^{1/2} \ \ , \ $ then the Product and Chain Rules give us

$$ \frac{dA}{dr} \ \ =  \ \ \frac{6 \pi^2r^5 \ + \ \mathbf{18V·\frac{dV}{dr}} }{2·r·\sqrt{ \ \pi^2r^6 \ + \  9V^2 }} \ - \ \frac{\sqrt{\ \pi^2r^6 \ + \ 9V^2 }}{r^2} $$ $$ = \ \ \frac{3 \pi^2r^6 \ + \ 9·r·V\frac{dV}{dr} \ - \ ( \ \pi^2r^6 \ + \  9V^2 \ ) }{r^2 ·\sqrt{ \ \pi^2r^6 \ + \  9V^2 }} \ \  = \ \ \frac{2 \pi^2r^6 \ + \ 9 r V\frac{dV}{dr} \ - \    9V^2   }{r^2 ·\sqrt{ \ \pi^2r^6 \ + \  9V^2 }} \ \ , $$
upon placing the entire expression over a common denominator.

Differentiating implicitly with respect to $ \ r \ \ , \ $  the relation $ \ A^2r^2 \ = \ \pi^2r^6 \ + \  9V^2 \ $ produces

$$ 2Ar^2 · \frac{dA}{dr} \ + \ 2A^2r \ \    = \ \     6 \pi^2r^5 \  + \  18V\frac{dV}{dr}   \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{dA}{dr} \ \ = \ \ \frac{ 3 \pi^2r^5 \  + \  9V\frac{dV}{dr} \ - \ A^2r}{A·r^2} \ \ . $$

Substituting the original expression for $ \ A \ $ leads to

$$ \frac{dA}{dr} \ \ = \ \ \frac{  ( \ 3 \pi^2r^5 \  + \  9V\frac{dV}{dr} \ )  \ - \   \frac{  \pi^2r^6 \ + \  9V^2 }{r^2} · r }{r·\sqrt{ \ \pi^2r^6 \ + \  9V^2 }} $$ $$ = \ \ \frac{  ( \ 3 \pi^2r^5 \  + \  9V\frac{dV}{dr} \ )·r  \ - \   \frac{  \pi^2r^6 \ + \  9V^2 }{r^2} · r^2 }{r^2·\sqrt{ \ \pi^2r^6 \ + \  9V^2 }} $$
$$ = \ \ \frac{  3 \pi^2r^6 \  + \  9rV\frac{dV}{dr}    \ - \     ( \ \pi^2r^6 \ + \  9V^2 \ )  }{r^2·\sqrt{ \ \pi^2r^6 \ + \  9V^2 }} \ \ ,   $$
which gives the same result as found above.

So the **total**  derivative (as remarked by **Guangliang**) found from either method *is* the same.  If $ \ V \ $ is independent of $ \ r \ \ ,  \ $ the term $ \ 9rV\frac{dV}{dr} \ $ will be absent in both methods.